# Styling Toggle Button to Achieve Custom Look

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented a Toggle Button using Material-UI and styled-components in my React application. However, I am facing challenges in achieving the desired custom styling for the Toggle Button.

**Current Implementation:**

I have defined a StyledToggleButtonGroup using styled-components that overrides the default styling of the Material-UI ToggleButtonGroup. Inside the StyledToggleButtonGroup, I have specified styles for the MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped class to customize the appearance of the individual toggle buttons. I also have a toggleBtnStyles function that conditionally applies styles based on the current alignment state.

**Desired Custom Look:**

I want to achieve a custom look for the toggle buttons, where each button has a arrow shape on the bottom. I have attached an image link for reference.

[image]

**Current Look:**

I have also attached an image link to show the current appearance of my Toggle Button. As you can see, it does not match the desired custom look.

[image]

What I've Tried:
I have experimented with different styles in the StyledToggleButtonGroup and the toggleBtnStyles function, but so far, I haven't been able to achieve the desired look.

**Code**

```
const StyledToggleButtonGroup = styled(ToggleButtonGroup)(({ theme }) => ({
'& .MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped': {
  margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
  color: '#FFF',
  backgroundColor: '#000',
  '&.Mui-selected': {
    color: '#000',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },
  '&.Mui-disabled': {
    border: 0,
  },
  '&:not(:first-of-type)': {
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    borderLeft: '#000',
  },
  '&:first-of-type': {
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  },
  '& span': {
    textTransform: 'none',
  },
},
marginBottom: '20px',
}))
const toggleBtnStyles = (alignment: any) => ({
toggleBtn: {
  marginRight: '10px',
  color: alignment === 'personalBusiness' ? '#FFF' : '#000',
  backgroundColor: alignment === 'personalBusiness' ? '#606060' : '#FFF',
},
commercialToggleBtn: {
  color: alignment === 'commercial' ? '#FFF' : '#000',
  backgroundColor: alignment === 'commercial' ? '#606060' : '#FFF',
},
})

  <StyledToggleButtonGroup
                  size='small'
                  value={alignment}
                  exclusive
                  onChange={handleAlignment}
                  aria-label='text alignment'>
                  <ToggleButton
                    value='Business'
                    aria-label='Business'
                    style={toggleBtnStyles(alignment).toggleBtn}>
                    <span>Business</span>
                  </ToggleButton>
                  <ToggleButton
                    value='commercial'
                    aria-label='commercial'
                    style={toggleBtnStyles(alignment).commercialToggleBtn}>
                    <span>Commercial</span>
                  </ToggleButton>
                </StyledToggleButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by customizing `sx` prop. You can find a simple example below . You can make `ToggleButton` a reusable component which include all `ToggleButtonProp` and an additional prop to check the state of the `<ToggleGroup/>` and use this additional state to change the colors for active/inactive state

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState('web')

<ToggleButtonGroup color="primary" exclusive value={myState} onChange={(_, val: string) => setMyState(val)}>
    <ToggleButton
      value="web"
      className="toggleButton"
      sx={{
        color: 'white',
        bgcolor: 'red',
        border: 'none',
        '&.Mui-selected': { bgcolor: 'grey', color: 'white' },
        '&.Mui-selected:hover': { bgcolor: 'grey' },
        ':hover': { bgcolor: 'red' },
        ':after': {
          content: "''",
          position: 'absolute',
          top: '100%',
          left: '50%',
          ml: '-10px',
          border: '10px solid',
          borderColor: `${myState === 'web' ? 'grey' : 'red'} transparent transparent transparent`,
        },}}
     >
      Web
    </ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

[image]